# How does an OS pick up the correct ico/favicon size?

Tags: html, favicon, head, ico

[Based on this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526747/ideal-size-for-ico), one can provide various sizes in a single file and the " OS will pick the best one to show."

How does this work?  Do we assign several of them where one declaration fallsback on the other?

Answer (score 4):

For desktop browsers, you are supposed to have a `favicon.ico` file and several PNG icons.

[`favicon.ico` should contain three pictures: 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740(v=vs.85).aspx) There can be several PNG icons, depending of the platforms to support: 16x16 and 32x32 for desktop browsers, 196x196 for Android Chrome, etc. Each picture is declared with something like `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">`.

The browsers have different attitudes toward picking the right icon:

- Up to Windows 7, Internet Explorer uses `favicon.ico`, [as described by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740(v=vs.85).aspx).
- Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8 pick the biggest PNG icon it can find.
- Chrome uses the 16x16 (Windows) or 32x32 (Mac) PNG icon.
- Firefox uses the latest declared PNG icon (see [bug 751712](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751712)), although [it apparently doesn't always behave that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873851/how-to-find-out-which-favicon-a-browser-actually-uses/33898053).
- Safari uses the biggest PNG icon it can find.

These results come from the [compatibility page of RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility). Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Comment: @ayjay Yep! If you are looking for some ready-to-use material, have a look to http://realfavicongenerator.net/ , it generates everything for you.

Comment: @philippe_b Anyway we can induce a particular behavior? Like, can we, somehow, dictate the browser to use the 48*48 image?

Comment: Also, how does it work with Edge browser? I have a set of favicons but none of them work with Edge

Comment: @MV23 Edge usually picks the 32x32 PNG icon. However, Edge is known to be troublesome regarding local sites (typically: with the site you are developing right now). So if your favicon works with every browsers but Edge, I suggest you to ignore the issue for now and check again once your site is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

As per the excellent article from Jonathan T. Neal at http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/ it depends on which browser you are using:

> Firefox and Safari will use the favicon that comes last. Chrome for
>   Mac will use whichever favicon is ICO formatted, otherwise the 32×32
>   favicon. Chrome for Windows will use the favicon that comes first if
>   it is 16×16, otherwise the ICO. If none of the aforementioned options
>   are available, both Chromes will use whichever favicon comes first,
>   exactly the opposite of Firefox and Safari. Indeed, Chrome for Mac
>   will ignore the 16×16 favicon and use the 32×32 version if only to
>   scale it back down to 16×16 on non-retina devices. Opera, not wanting
>   to take sides, will choose from any of the available icons at complete
>   random. I love that Opera does this.